# regex to extract the text ignoring the comments

Tags: regex

Using a regex I need to be extract the text between : and the comment /* so that the output is Verdana, Arial, sans-serif. Any pointers on how to approach this problem would be helpful.

```
: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif /*{ffDefault}*/;
```

Comment: is that an example of the complete line you would be parsing?

Comment: yes. Another possibility of the complete line would be :  /*{ffDefault}*/ Verdana, Arial, sans-serif /*{ffDefault}*/; (OR) /*{ffDefault}*/ Verdana, Arial,  /*{ffDefault}*/ sans-serif /*{ffDefault}*/;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Learning Regular Expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do:

```
:\s*([^/]+)\s*/\*\{[^}]*\}\*/
```

The only captured group is your desired portion.

- `:\s*` matches a `:`, followed by any number of whitespaces
- `([^/]+)` matches upto the next `/` and put in a captured group
- `\s*` matches zero or more whitespaces, followed by comment (`/\*\{[^}]*\}\*/`)

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/GdbCgj/4)

Comment: At a glance, it looks like he may be parsing a CSS file so it may not need the starting carrot.

Comment: Thanks, what if I want to ignore any comments on the same line for eg: if the string is :  /*{ffDefault}*/ Verdana, Arial, sans-serif /*{ffDefault}*/;

Comment: @web_dev Do: `(?:\/\*\{[^}]*\}\*\/)?\s*([^\/]+)\s*\/\*\{[^}]*\}\*\/`. Check https://regex101.com/r/GdbCgj/3